# My code randomly stops and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm not sure why my code is not working? After asking the user to enter the grades for test administered, it just stops and displays the user input for the first student without asking for any information for the others.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var names = new Array(); 
var tests = new Array();
var high =0; 
var low = 0;  

    var numOfStudents = prompt("How many students are in the class? "); 
    numOfStudents = parseInt(numOfStudents);

    var i = 0; 
    for (i=0; i<=numOfStudents - 1; i++){
        names[i] = prompt("Enter the students name: "); 
        document.write("Name of Student: " + names[i]);
        var numOfTest = prompt("How many test were administered for this student? ");
        numOfTest = parseInt(numOfTest);
            for (i=0; i<=numOfTest -1; i++){
                tests[i] = prompt("Enter the test grade: "); 
                document.write(" Grade: "+ tests[i] + "<br />"); 
                        }
    }


</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of `new Array()` just do `[]`

Comment: You are using counting variable "i" in the outer loop for students, and again in the inner loop for grades...

Comment: It's worth noting that since this is client-side JavaScript, getting input through `prompt()` is extremely backwards. It's trivial to make a `<form>` with input elements in it you can pull values from, and you can trigger behaviour either `onchange` or `onsubmit` with less code than this. If you're learning JavaScript, that's great, but don't forget you've got a whole *browser* there to take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

Choose another variable name for the second loop

```
for (var j=0; j<=numOfTest -1; j++){
                tests[j] = prompt("Enter the test grade: "); 
                document.write(" Grade: "+ tests[j] + "<br />"); 
                        }
```